# mongo load_models giving error when using enum inside STI in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, enums

I am using Singe Table Inheritance in rails.

```
module ModuleName
  class ParentClass < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum status: {OPEN: 'open', CLOSED: 'closed'}
  end
end

module ModuleName
  class ChildClass1 < ParentClass
  end
end

module ModuleName
  class ChildClass2 < ParentClass
  end
end
```

Migrations and localhost server in running fine, however on executing command:-

```
bundle exec rake db:mongoid:remove_indexes
```

or

```
bundle exec rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```

I am getting error.

```
ArgumentError: You tried to define an enum named "status" on the model "ModuleName::ParentClass", but this will generate a instance method "status=", which is already defined by another enum.
Tasks: TOP => db:mongoid:remove_indexes => db:mongoid:load_models
```

As a hit and trial, I tried removing status enum from parent class and put them into child classes seperately instead. Did not work.

Could not find any relevant help on internet.
Any help or suggestions appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

The issue occurs whenever models are eagerloaded. db:mongoid:load_models does that. Migrations and rails server will fail too if you have

```
config.eager_load = true
```

in your config file

Solution is more of a workaround. It works by declaring enum as:-

```
enum status: {OPEN: 'open', CLOSED: 'closed'} unless instance_methods.include? :status
```